# Core Data NSInternalInconsistencyException on single background thread delete function

Tags: objective-c, core-data

My project has a database handler and one of its function is delete almost all records from the database.  I execute the actual deleting on a single background thread.  Sometimes my code works fine sometimes it crashes with a NSInternalInconsistencyException.  Currently it fails 1 out of 3 tries.  Why am I getting a NSInternalInconsistencyException?  I thought this only happens when your multi-threading your core data function. Here's my code:

```
//Database handler init.
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        //getting the managedobjectcontext from appdelegate
        self.managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        //background queue
        self.backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("database.queue", NULL);
        status = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

//delete majority of the database entry
- (void) clearTables
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, ^(void) {

        NSError *error;

         //update this entity records.
        for(Entity1 *object in [self queryEntity:@"Entity1"]) {
            object.download_ymdhms = nil;
            [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        }

        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        NSLog(@"error1: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        //Delete the other entities data.   
        for(Entity2 *object in [self queryEntity:@"Entity2"]) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
        }
        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        NSLog(@"error2: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        for(Entity3 *object in [self queryEntity:@"Entity3"]) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
        }

        ...

        for(Entity10 *object in [self queryEntity:@"Entity10"]) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
        }

        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        NSLog(@"error3: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        //notify deletion complete
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"database.queue.delete.done" object:nil];
    });
}

//get all the objects in an entity.
- (NSArray *) queryEntity: (NSString *)entity {
    return [self queryEntity:entity withPredicate:nil withLimit:0 orderBy:nil];
}

...

//general query
- (NSArray *) queryEntity: (NSString *)entity withPredicate: (NSString *)predicate withLimit: (int)limit orderBy: (NSString *)order
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    if(predicate.length > 0) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicate]];
    }

    if(limit > 0) {
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:limit];
    }

    if(order.length > 0) {
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:order ascending:YES]]];
    }

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return results;
}
```

This is the error that I sometimes get:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  statement is still active with userInfo (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'
```

Edit: added code comments to make it more readable.

Comment: I don't think you can just call the main context on a background thread.  You have to create the context on the background thread if you want to use it there.  Try running it all on the main thread and see if you get any errors.

Comment: If I run everything in the main thread, the UI display freezes.  Deleting all this data takes anywhere between 15-30 seconds.

Comment: Sure I understand the UI will freeze if you do that, but you should'nt get any errors, no good for production though.  To fix it properly create another managedObjectContext on the background thread and then perform your deletes on the same thread using that MOC. You can't use the main thread managedObjectContext.